# If the ListView is not visible, does refresh code execute?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using Visual Basic.net and have a question: If I have a piece of code, such as refreshing a ListView, and the form that the ListView is on is not currently visible, does this code execute? I am just wondering if it is a waste of memory to execute this code, or if it is not executed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're firing a timer, and that timer is executing code that refreshes the display of the list view, it will execute, but the display will not refresh until you ... actually display it to the user.

In other words, the ListView's state gets updated with the changes, but the changes aren't displayed until the form is visible.  No video card pixels are harmed in the updating of the hidden ListView, in other words.

Answer (score 2):

Refreshing listview doesn't harm/waste memory unless the data(Listview items) are too many. If your code contains retrival of listview items for some other controls or dynamic manipulations based on data/items from the listview then refreshing listview is needed.

Comment: Accepted & modified accordingly